# Why am I unable to grab this input element's default value?

Tags: jquery

Here is a demonstration of the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/92m4309b/

I have an `input` element whose `value` attribute I am trying to read. For some reason, I am unable to read it using jQuery, it returns an empty string.

html

```
<input type="file" 
   style="display:none;" 
   accept="video/mp4, video/ogv" 
   id="some-random-id" 
   name="some-random-text-input" 
   value="30_sec_Verizon4.mp4"
>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 console.log($("input").val());
 console.log($("input").attr('value'));
});
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: a file type input doesn't have a default value as far as I know!

Comment: Code relevant to the question should be pasted into the question.  External references have a habit of getting changed or disappearing and then this question becomes worthless as a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the prop()-method. See the docs for more details: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

```
$("#some-random-id").prop("defaultValue");
```